# How-to: Run existing Word VBA Macros from C# Ribbon Addin

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, ms-word

Background: I have an extensive set of specialized VBA macros used in Word for document formatting purposes. In Word 2003, these macros were activated from a customized toolbar. I have recently transitioned to Word 2007 and would like to be able to run these existing VBA macros from a new Word Ribbon created with VS 2010. I have created a Ribbon; however, I cannot figure out how to call the existing macros from the new Ribbon buttons.

Question: How do I call the existing VBA macros, which are stored in a .dotm template, from the C# Word Add-in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique described in [MS KB article 306683](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683) -- in particular, function `RunMacro` defined there -- should allow you to call a VBA macro from within C# code: You define a function `RunMacro`

```
private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
    oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, oApp, oRunArgs);
}
```

and then call your macro like this:

```
RunMacro(oApp, new object[] {"NameOfMyMacro"})
```

or

```
RunMacro(oApp, new object[] {"NameOfMyMacro", "some", 3, "parameters"})
```

`oApp` is the `Word.Application` object, which I'm sure is available somewhere in a Word add-in.

Comment: If i used this code in excel template it wil generate macro security warning...How can i supress this?

Comment: @Smack: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-macro-security-settings-in-excel-HP010096919.aspx