# How to deploy C# code and VBA scripts in one VSTO Word addin

Tags: c#, vba, clickonce, vsto

Underlying problem I was trying to solve is to apply custom key bindings for internal VSTO Word addin methods (develiped in C#):

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.KeyBindings.Add(  
    Word.WdKeyCategory.wdKeyCategoryCommand,  
    "MyMethodName",  
    myKey,
    ref _missing,  
    ref _missing);
```

Well, the problem is that this code always throws an exception because (Microsoft MSDN): “there's no way (in the object model or Word application) to bind to anything but VBA macros”.

What other developers are trying to do is to implement a workaround with VBA method that assign key bindings to VBA callbacks when addin loads, and call C# addin from those callbacks in turn. (see how to [call VBA from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735815/how-to-run-existing-word-vba-macros-from-c-ribbon-addin) for details)

This idea has a chance for live: .NET AddIn and VBA-enabled Word template. But in my project I need to deliver this addin in a single Click Once package to end-user machines (inside a corporate network where security settings are not an issue).

So the Question is: how to make a mix of C# Add-In (Ribbon) and VBA scripts in one deployment package?

Does anyone has such experience to share?

Comment: Here is a solution for VSTO4 (.NET 4): "Walkthrough: Deploying Multiple Office Solutions in a Single ClickOnce Installer for the .NET Framework 4" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465290(VS.100).aspx). How about VSTO3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here we go!

[Walkthrough: Deploying Multiple Office Solutions in a Single ClickOnce Installer for the .NET Framework 3.5.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382205(VS.100)).aspx)

A lot of hand work. But the idea is to update ClickOnce package with additional dependencies (edit manifest XML). Standard ClickOnce setup program will do the rest for you.

Comment: Good find Ghen. You can go ahead and accept your own answer (the check mark thingy) so that this thread shows as "answered".

Comment: When you click link, it shows alternative link suggestion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382205.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hmmm seems like a workaround when you can just use windows subclassing to bind directly to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the ClickOnce product team your question. He said you can include the scripts in the VSTO deployment, and you can do post-deployment steps with a VSTO add-in if you are targeting .NET 4.0. He said you might also be able to do this through VBA Interop features in VSTO. Do you happen to be targeting .NET 4.0?